# why does will_paginate .maximum return nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I have a typical users table with 40 rows. When I call .maximum on a will_paginate .paginate result I get the expected result when page is either nil or 1:

> (byebug) User.paginate(page: nil, per_page: 5).maximum(:id)
>
> 1036274506
>
> (byebug) User.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 5).maximum(:id)
>
> 1036274506

But when page is 2 .maximum returns nil.

> (byebug) User.paginate(page: 2, per_page: 5).maximum(:id)
>
> nil

What I need is a min and max value of a particular column from the .paginate result set before I do the rest of my downstream processing. I know I can call .order on this column and then .first and .last but that will throw off the existing ordering which I need for downstream processing.

My questions are:

1. Why is .maximum returning nil when page is 2?
2. Am I missing a simple solution to easily grabbing min/max from this column?

I'll hack it if I have to but was hoping first to understand what's going on here and second to avoid hacking.

I'm using Rails 5.0.1 and WillPaginate 3.1.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 5).maximum(:id) will fire 
query with OFFSET 0

`mysql> SELECT  MAX(`users`.`id`) FROM`users`WHERE`users`.`trashed_at`IS NULL LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
+-------------------+
| MAX(`users`.`id`) |
+-------------------+
|        1036274506 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

User.paginate(page: 2, per_page: 5).maximum(:id) fire query with OFFSET 5

`SELECT  MAX(`users`.`id`) FROM`users`WHERE`users`.`trashed_at`IS NULL LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5;
Empty set (0.00 sec)`

Not sure but i think max is not working with offset,

You can use `User.paginate(page:2 , per_page: 2).pluck(:id).max` for maximum id.